# Facing issue regarding react-perfect-scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar

I'm facing an issue with as scrollbar package(React-Perfect-Scrollbar). Actually this is not issue but default behaviour of scrollbar functionality, while loading list of image. I've given default min-height to image(50px). So, initially scrollbar will cover the scroll area as per the current height of the div, but as soon as the image will load scrollbar adjust its size as per the new height because different image have different height. Because of the entire behaviour i'm seeing the fluctuation in the size of the scrollbar. Is there any way using that way i can overcome this scrollbar?

i have tried some CSS and react-perfect-scrollbar npm package features but not getting the required solution.